# character set encoding issue with multi-language featured site

Tags: character-encoding, meta-tags

I am here suffering from a simple, common problem.

my site is multi-language featured, built in codeigniter framework.

for eg for a french language here  i have used

```
$lang['login'] = 'ConnÈcter';
```

this then appeared as Conn�cter in the view.

then i solved this by adding

```
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
```

which then resolved the issue.
but when the contents is loaded with characters like

```
Sáenz-Mata & Jiménez-Bremont
```

then is is changed to

```
SÃ¡enz-Mata & JimÃ©nez-Bremont
```

note é is changed to Ã© even when i use

```
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
```

when above meta is removed, it gives me Conn�cter when the language is converted to french.

so please suggest me something which can handle both situations.

hope somebody understands it.(got messed up describing.)

thanks.

Comment: Very common indeed. Do some reading: [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/), [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Answer (score 0):

use `<meta charset="utf-8">`

Comment: yes, utf-8 gives Conn�cter for ConnÈcter but Sáenz-Mata comes in format. i.e. the french languages from the french files in codeigniter is messed up.

Answer (score 0):

Use UTF-8 consistently for all pages, as explained in the [CodeIgniter User guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html). Make sure the encoding of each file matches its declared encoding. What you are experiencing now is caused by mixing encodings (UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1 mostly).